# Update Query with a variable instance

Tags: python-3.x

First and foremost, I must admit I am new to Python and SQL. Now, I will get the problem. I am trying to update a table where column_ID is equivalent to a variable. In the Python class I have a function with the following statement:

```
stName = self.txtName.text()
stUsername = self.txtUsername.text()
stPassword = self.txtPassword.text()
stMobile = self.txtMobile.text()
myID = self.txtID.text()

sql_update_query = """UPDATE signup SET name = %s, username = %s, password = %s, mobile = %s WHERE id = myID"""

input = (stName, stUsername, stPassword, stMobile)

curs.execute(sql_update_query, input)

conn.commit()
```

When I click the Update button to run this function, the system prompts 'Python has stopped working'.

Can someone assist me to fix the SQL statement?

Comment: *the system prompts 'Python has stopped working*

seems like an ambiguous error, can you edit your question with the whole trace-back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myID` needs to be passed as an argument to the sql statement.

```
sql_update_query = """UPDATE signup SET name = %s, username = %s, password = %s, mobile = %s WHERE id = %s"""
```

And

```
input = (stName, stUsername, stPassword, stMobile, myID)
```